# Check if controller has passed optional function down to *child* directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a scenario as follows:

Controller A >> Directive "parent" >> Directive "child"

Controller B >> Directive "parent" >> Directive "child"

Both directives have isolated scopes, and I cannot use transclusion.

Controller A defines a function that is passed down to the child directive (using the "&?" notation in both directives).

```
<div parent fx="doFx()"></div>
```

Controller B does NOT specify that function.

```
<div parent></div>
```

The parent directive simply passes down the function to the child directive.

```
<div child fx="doFx()"></div>
```

How can I check **in the child directive** (without accessing the parent's scope) whether or not the controller did in fact pass a function?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Why do you want to check it, you can still call it nothing bad will happen if it hasn't been passed. Anyway, I don't think there is a good way to do it easily.

Comment: The markup associated with the child directive must look different if the action is not available. For a starter, the button that triggers the function should be hidden - plus a couple of other things. Of course, I can pass another scope variable down for this sake, but I thought the presence/absence of the function itself should be enough... if detectable, that is...

Comment: No, it's quite tricky. I would try to solve it with the help of helper flag on the parent directive controller (check if attribute is present) and then requiring parent controller from child.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that the only option would be to access the parent's scope... which your statement seems to confirm :(

Comment: No, don't use parent scope. I meant parent controller, not scope. Parent scope would be pretty bad option.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible with third argument passed to linking function.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('Example', function () {
  this.fn1 = function () {
    return true;
  };
});

angular.module('app').directive('someDir', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '{{isPassed}}',
    scope: {
      fx: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.isPassed = attrs['fx'] !== undefined && attrs['fx'].length > 0;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Ex">
  A: <some-dir></some-dir> <br>
  B: <some-dir fx></some-dir><br>
  C: <some-dir fx="Ex.fn1"></some-dir>
</div>
```

edit:
You can also use specific return value.

```js
const PASSED = 'PASSED';

angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('Example', function() {
  this.fn1 = function() {
    return PASSED;
  };
});

angular.module('app').directive('parent', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<child fx="fx()"></child>',
    scope: {
      fx: '&'
    }
  };
});

angular.module('app').directive('child', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '{{isPassed}}',
    scope: {
      fx: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.isPassed = scope.fx() === PASSED;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Ex">
  A: <parent></parent><br>
  B: <parent fx="Ex.fn1()"></parent><br>
</div>
```

But in my opinion best solution would be to use first attrs to check if fx is passed and explicitly pass isPassed to child directive.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('Example', function() {
  this.fn1 = function() {};
});

angular.module('app').directive('parent', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<child fx="fx()" is-passed="isPassed"></child>',
    scope: {
      fx: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.isPassed = attrs['fx'] !== undefined && attrs['fx'].length > 0;
    }
  };
});

angular.module('app').directive('child', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '{{isPassed}}',
    scope: {
      fx: '&',
      isPassed: '<'
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Ex">
  A: <parent></parent><br>
  B: <parent fx="Ex.fn1()"></parent><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you are missing the point: I know that I can use the link function to check if an attribute is present. However in my scenario the check would be in the child directive (2 levels down), which would always find the "fx" attribute because the parent directive has it as a pass-through.

Comment: You cant do that, but you can require parent controller. I would pass this explicitly. Other than that you can use return value.

Comment: @PlanetPaolo I updated my answer with one other possible solution and example showing that my first solution is correct, you just need to be willing to use it correctly. There is nothing wrong with explicit parameter on child directive.